How to correctly use authentication_policy for MySQL 8.0
The documentation states that this setting replaces deprecated default_authentication_plugin. It also states that it can be set like this in cnf file:
[mysqld]
authentication_policy = *:auth_plugin

So I tried this
[mysqld]
authentication_policy = *:mysql_native_password

After I do this I get error in the log
[ERROR] [MY-013797] [Server] Option --authentication-policy is set to an 
invalid value. Please check if the specified authentication plugins are valid.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_authentication_policy
Additional info:
This configuration works
[mysqld]
authentication_policy = mysql_native_password

This one does not
[mysqld]
authentication_policy = mysql_native_password, caching_sha2_password

Mysql 8.0.39, Ubuntu 22.04

no it is a string with comma seperated values like '*,'  for all or '*,*,*' the asterisk can be replaaced with a specific text value like  'caching_sha2_password, authentication_fido, sha256_password'

If I set it to just one auth plugin it works, like this authentication_policy authentication_fido, if i add one more it dumps error again

post your working solution and that which doesn't

Mysqkl 8,4 doesn't even allow mysql_native_password , but i think ou need to add another plugins when ou want to add them
